# Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 2490755129) error in ffmpeg which creates HLS and in ffmpeg which uploads HLS to a CDN

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

ffmpeg command which creates the hls stream:
`ffmpeg -y -v warning -i udp://225.1.2.3:2000?reuse=1&buffer_size=16777216&localaddr=127.0.0.1&overrun_nonfatal=1 -c:v:0 h264_qsv -global_quality 25 -pix_fmt nv12 -r 59.94 -filter:v:0 fps=fps=59.94,scale=768:432:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=768:432:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2 -vsync cfr -g 120 -c:a:0 aac -ar 48000 -b:a:0 128k -profile:v:0 high -level:v:0 3.1 -b:v:0 1000k -maxrate:v:0 1000k -bufsize:v:0 1000k -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v:1 h264 -global_quality 25 -pix_fmt nv12 -r 24 -filter:v:1 fps=fps=24,scale=640:360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:360:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2 -vsync cfr -g 121 -c:a:1 aac -ar 44100 -b:a:1 128k -profile:v:1 main -level:v:1 3.1 -b:v:1 800k -maxrate:v:1 800k -bufsize:v:1 800k -map 0:v -map 0:a -max_muxing_queue_size 4096 -f hls -hls_list_size 10 -hls_delete_threshold 30 -hls_flags delete_segments -hls_time 4 -master_pl_name master.m3u8 -var_stream_map " v:0,a:0,name:0 v:1,a:1,name:1" -hls_start_number_source epoch C:path_to_hls_data/436379cd-11e6-4ef0-a198-58c69b139803/%v_playlist.m3u8`

ffmpeg command to upload the hls stream to cdn:
`ffmpeg -y -v warning -re -f hls -http_persistent 0 -i http://localhost:3000/assets/436379cd-11e6-4ef0-a198-58c69b139803/master.m3u8 -b:v:0 1000k -b:a:0 128k -c:v:0 copy -c:a:0 copy -b:v:1 800k -b:a:1 128k -c:v:1 copy -c:a:1 copy -method POST -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:1 -map 0:a:1 -var_stream_map " v:0,a:0,name:0 v:1,a:1,name:1" -f hls -master_pl_name master.m3u8 -hls_list_size 10 -hls_time 4 -hls_flags second_level_segment_index -master_pl_publish_rate 150 -strftime 1 -hls_segment_filename "cdn_link" "cdn_link"`

> In the logs below _UploaderProcess  is the ffmpeg which uploads the hls stream to cdn, _encProcess_dst is the ffmpeg which creates the hls stream

Error logs:

```
6961    19:42:40.241    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:42:40.241 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: [mpegts @ 0000026eabff7c40] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 1805890264).

6960    19:42:36.204    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:42:36.204 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: [hls @ 0000026eabfecb40] skipping 3 segments ahead, expired from playlists

6959    19:42:27.520    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:42:27.520 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _encProcess_dst stderr: [h264 @ 0000025030f09540] co located POCs unavailable
6958    19:42:27.516    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:42:27.516 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _encProcess_dst stderr: [h264 @ 0000025030f0a780] co located POCs unavailable
6957    19:42:27.514    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:42:27.514 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _encProcess_dst stderr: [h264 @ 0000025030f0c780] co located POCs unavailable
6956    19:42:27.504    2021-05-08  Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
6955    19:42:27.504    2021-05-08  [aac @ 000002502ff97c40] Number of scalefactor bands in group (57) exceeds limit (49).
6954    19:42:27.504    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:42:27.504 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _encProcess_dst stderr: [aac @ 000002502ff97c40] Reserved bit set.
6953    19:42:27.503    2021-05-08  Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
6952    19:42:27.503    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:42:27.503 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _encProcess_dst stderr: [aac @ 000002502ff97c40] Number of bands (50) exceeds limit (41).
6951    19:42:27.501    2021-05-08  [mpegts @ 000002502ff6cdc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 5313003).
6950    19:42:27.501    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:42:27.501 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _encProcess_dst stderr: [mpegts @ 000002502ff6cdc0] PES packet size mismatch
6949    19:42:27.498    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:42:27.498 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _encProcess_dst stderr: [mpegts @ 000002502ff6cdc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 5327196).
6948    19:42:24.201    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:42:24.201 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: [mpegts @ 0000026eabff7c40] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 1804448823).
6947    19:42:20.193    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:42:20.193 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: [hls @ 0000026eabfecb40] skipping 2 segments ahead, expired from playlists
6946    19:42:08.190    2021-05-08  [mpegts @ 0000026eabff7c40] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 1803007381).
6945    19:42:08.190    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:42:08.190 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: Last message repeated 1 times
6944    19:41:48.169    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:41:48.169 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: [hls @ 0000026eabfecb40] skipping 2 segments ahead, expired from playlists
6943    19:41:44.289    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:41:44.289 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _encProcess_dst stderr: [mpegts @ 000002502ff6cdc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 1445819).
6942    19:41:36.153    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:41:36.153 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: [mpegts @ 0000026eabff7c40] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 1800124498).
6941    19:41:34.154    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:41:34.154 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: [hls @ 0000026eabfecb40] skipping 2 segments ahead, expired from playlists
6940    19:41:31.565    2021-05-08  Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
6939    19:41:31.565    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:41:31.565 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _encProcess_dst stderr: [aac @ 000002502ff97c40] skip_data_stream_element: Input buffer exhausted before END element found
6938    19:41:31.564    2021-05-08  Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
6937    19:41:31.564    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:41:31.564 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _encProcess_dst stderr: [aac @ 000002502ff97c40] Number of bands (46) exceeds limit (41).
6936    19:41:31.498    2021-05-08  [mpegts @ 000002502ff6cdc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 185153643).
6935    19:41:31.498    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:41:31.498 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _encProcess_dst stderr: [mpegts @ 000002502ff6cdc0] PES packet size mismatch
6934    19:41:31.486    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:41:31.486 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _encProcess_dst stderr: [h264 @ 0000025030f0be80] co located POCs unavailable
6933    19:41:31.484    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:41:31.484 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _encProcess_dst stderr: [h264 @ 0000025030f0b540] co located POCs unavailable
6932    19:41:31.483    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:41:31.483 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _encProcess_dst stderr: [h264 @ 0000025030f0b0c0] co located POCs unavailable
6931    19:41:31.480    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:41:31.480 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _encProcess_dst stderr: [mpegts @ 000002502ff6cdc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 185167857).
6930    19:41:31.447    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:41:31.447 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _tspProcess_play stderr: * Warning: regulate: out of sequence PCR, maybe source was cycling, restarting regulation
6929    19:41:22.164    2021-05-08  [mpegts @ 0000026eabff7c40] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 1798863237).
6928    19:41:22.164    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:41:22.164 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: Last message repeated 1 times
6927    19:41:02.119    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:41:02.119 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: [hls @ 0000026eabfecb40] skipping 2 segments ahead, expired from playlists
6926    19:40:50.147    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:40:50.147 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: [mpegts @ 0000026eabff7c40] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 1795980354).
6925    19:40:46.111    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:40:46.111 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: [hls @ 0000026eabfecb40] skipping 2 segments ahead, expired from playlists
6924    19:40:34.099    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:40:34.099 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: [mpegts @ 0000026eabff7c40] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 1794538913).
6923    19:40:30.074    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:40:30.074 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: [hls @ 0000026eabfecb40] skipping 2 segments ahead, expired from playlists
6922    19:40:18.062    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:40:18.062 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: [mpegts @ 0000026eabff7c40] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 1793097471).
6921    19:40:14.081    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:40:14.081 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: [hls @ 0000026eabfecb40] skipping 2 segments ahead, expired from playlists
6920    19:40:02.055    2021-05-08  [mpegts @ 0000026eabff7c40] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 1791656030).
6919    19:40:02.055    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:40:02.055 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: Last message repeated 1 times
6918    19:39:42.040    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:39:42.040 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: [hls @ 0000026eabfecb40] skipping 2 segments ahead, expired from playlists
6917    19:39:30.017    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:39:30.017 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: [mpegts @ 0000026eabff7c40] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 1788773147).
6916    19:39:26.014    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:39:26.014 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: [hls @ 0000026eabfecb40] skipping 2 segments ahead, expired from playlists
6915    19:39:13.996    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:39:13.996 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: [mpegts @ 0000026eabff7c40] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 1787331706).
6914    19:39:10.004    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:39:10.004 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: [hls @ 0000026eabfecb40] skipping 2 segments ahead, expired from playlists
6913    19:38:58.003    2021-05-08  [2021-05-08T19:38:58.003 DEBUG video_encoder.js:1] - _UploaderProcess stderr: [mpegts @ 0000026eabff7c40] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 1785890264).
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but you may want to change your "-g" factor to a similar figure as your frame rate. I was having muxrate issues and this error as well and that sorted me out. It may help you.

Also, you can try add "-fflags +discardcorrupt"